# Is there a pattern/formula to this?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics, pattern-recognition

I came across a nice "sequence" on a mathematics Facebook page and it intrigued me somewhat. This is not homework or anything of the sort, just something fun to start the year off I guess.

---

Observe the following:

\begin{align}
(1)^1 & =
1
\\[5 mm]
(8 + 1)^2 & =
81
\\[5 mm]
(5 + 1 + 2)^3 & =
512
\\[5 mm]
(2 + 4 + 0 + 1)^4 & =
2401
\end{align}

---

Some questions came to my mind almost immediately.

1. In general, is there a pattern/formula to this? For example, can we find the next (5-digit) number easily? Does it even exist? In particular, can we find a formula for the n-digit number?
2. For some of the numbers, the solutions are non-unique. For example, for the first power, obviously any digit would fit. Can we generalise this observation? In particular, do we know if the solution for every n-digit number, if it exists, is always non-unique?

P.S. The many brilliant minds on Math SE have never failed to amaze me, so I thought I should put this one up here to see what you guys can come up with :)

Comment: There are only three 5-digit fifth powers: $16807, 32768, 59049$. Direct observation shows that the sequence thus cannot be continued.

Comment: @player3236 How did you get those numbers so quickly? Is it through brute force computation? Also, how did you reach that conclusion? What direct observation did you observe? Could you write an answer?

Comment: See https://oeis.org/A128912 and also https://oeis.org/A076090

Comment: If you allow $0$ as a leading digit, you always have $(0+0+\cdots+0+1)^n=00\ldots01$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that we always have:

$$10^k = 1\underbrace{00...0}_{k \text { zeroes}}$$

which has $k+1$ digits. Hence for $n^k$ to have exactly $n$ digits, we must have $n < 10$.

For fifth powers, the first $9$ fifth powers are (http://oeis.org/A000584):

$$1, 32, 243, 1024, 3125, 7776, 16807, 32768, 59049$$

Now we look at the digit sums of $16807, 32768, 59049$, which are $22, 26, 27$ respectively, and are not equal to $7,8,9$. Hence we *cannot* have $(1+6+8+0+7)^5 = 16807$, etc.

A further question is, are there any more numbers in this sequence? If $9^k$ has less than $k$ digits, there are no $k$-digit $k$-th power. The number of digits (decimal) of a number $N$ is given by:

$$\lfloor\log_{10}N\rfloor+1$$

so if $9^k$ has less than $k$ digits, we have:

$$\lfloor\log_{10}9^k\rfloor+1 < k$$
$$k\log_{10}9 < k-1$$
$$k > \frac 1{1- \log_{10}9}\approx 21.854$$

hence we just need to verify the result up to $22$nd powers. (Observe that $9^{22}$ has only $21$ digits).

EDIT: the rest of the candidates are:

\begin{align}
7^6 &= 117649\\
8^6 &= 262144\\
8^7 &= 2097152\\
8^8 &= 16777216\\
8^9 &= 134217728\\
8^{10} &= 1073741824\\
9^6 &= 531441\\
9^7 &= 4782969\\
9^8 &= 43046721\\
9^9 &= 387420489\\
9^{10} &= 3486784401\\
9^{11} &= 31381059609\\
9^{12} &= 282429536481\\
9^{13} &= 2541865828329\\
9^{14} &= 22876792454961\\
9^{15} &= 205891132094649\\
9^{16} &= 1853020188851841\\
9^{17} &= 16677181699666569\\
9^{18} &= 150094635296999121\\
9^{19} &= 1350851717672992089\\
9^{20} &= 12157665459056928801\\
9^{21} &= 109418989131512359209
\end{align}

and none of these powers have digit sums equal to their bases.

Comment: PARI/GP `for(N=1,22,for(a=ceil(10^((N-1)/N)),9,if(a==vecsum(digits(a^N)),print([a,N,a^N]))))` finds no additional solutions

Comment: Thank you for your insightful answer. I would like to dive into the part where you say, "for $n^k$ to have exactly $n$ digits, we must have $n < 10$". I see that this is true. Then, would a consequence of this observation be that the digit sums must be, in itself, a single digit? For example, further in your answer, you write about $16807$, $32768$ and $59049$ and you mention that their digit sums are not equal to $7$, $8$ or $9$. Would it be more accurate to just say that their digit sums are not single digits?

Comment: It is not more accurate, but this observation does answer our question in the negative. The sum of digits of the power must be equal to the base, e.g. $2 + 4 + 0 + 1 = 7$. In general it is very hard for a power to have a sum of digits less than $10$ (except powers of $10$). I say "very hard", and it is (I believe) conjectured that there is no more for higher powers.

Comment: Also see https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Largest_nth_Power_which_has_n_Digits.

Comment: Note: SumDigits$(7^4) = 2+4+0+1 = 7$, and $7$ is the base of $7^4$.

Comment: Note that $6^5 = 7776$ only has $4$ digits. Hence for $k > 5$, $6^k$ has less than $k$ digits, since $6^k < 6^5 (10^{k-5})$, which has $4+k-5 = k -1$ digits. The powers with smaller bases have even less digits, so they don't need to be checked. “the sum of the digits of the power must be equal to the base” is the basis of your sequence, no?

Comment: I see. I get it now. Thank you so much for your patience :) also, I apologise for deleting my comments. I had not realised you had already seen them, because I didn’t get the notifications to your responses, so I wanted to consolidate my thoughts more before writing another comment.